# SQL - Trying to get employees with greater than average department salary

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get the average salary for a department, then use that to get any employee who makes above that average.

My query is:

```
select e.first_name, e.salary, e.department_id from
employees as e
inner join departments as d
on d.id = e.department_id
where salary > (select avg(e.salary)
  from employees as e
  where e.department_id = d.id
  group by e.department_id);
```

But it's only returning a single result, "Ian".

```
 first_name | salary | department_id 
------------+--------+---------------
 Ian        |  80000 |             2
(1 row)

        avg         
--------------------
 35000.000000000000
(1 row)

 id | first_name | last_name | salary | department_id 
----+------------+-----------+--------+---------------
  1 | John       | Smith     |  20000 |             1
  2 | Ava        | Muffinson |  10000 |             5
  3 | Cailin     | Ninson    |  30000 |             2
  4 | Mike       | Peterson  |  20000 |             2
  5 | Ian        | Peterson  |  80000 |             2
  6 | John       | Mills     |  50000 |             3
(6 rows)

 id |    name     
----+-------------
  1 | Reporting
  2 | Engineering
  3 | Marketing
  4 | Biz Dev
  5 | Silly Walks
(5 rows)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Your query is fine. For your sample data, `Ian` is the only result which should be returned.

Comment: Note you don't need a `group by` in the subquery since you want to aggregate over all results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are probably the best solution -- as in @zealous's answer.  However, a subquery is also very reasonable.  The idea is:

```
select e.first_name, e.salary, e.department_id
from employees as e
where e.salary > (select avg(e2.salary)
                  from employees e2
                  where e2.department_id = e.department_id
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=afe68c95ab38652a105568dfa994c192) is a db<>fiddle.

Key ideas:

- You don't need to `join` to `departments`.  Just because you have the idea doesn't mean the `join` is necessary.
- The `GROUP BY` is unnecessary in the subquery.  The correlation clause takes care of that.

Comment: Like this, but only returns one row in my environment.

Comment: @mr-sk . . . Of course.  Your sample data has three departments with only one employee.  That employee cannot have an average higher than the department average -- that employee's salary IS the department average.

Answer (score 0):

Start with just the salary per department in one prequery..  That should be basis for all employees after.

```
select
      e.*,
      JustAvgs.DptAvg
   from
      ( select 
              e.department_id,
              avg(e.salary) DptAvg
           from 
              employees as e
           group by 
              e.department_id) JustAvgs
         JOIN employees e
            on JustAvgs.Department_id = e.Department_ID
           AND e.Salary > JustAvgs.DptAvg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tYGpwDQtRGfbBsoxMnbW1M/4).

```
select  
    first_name,
    salary,
    department_id
from
(select
    department_id,
    first_name,
    salary,
    avg(salary) over () as avg_salary
from employee
) emp
where salary > avg_salary
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------+
first_name  salary  department_id|
+--------------------------------+
| Ian       80000      2         |
| John      50000      3         |
+--------------------------------+
```